# Misleading AttributeError

Tags: python, django-models, attributeerror

```
class Account(models.Model):
    holds_ready = models.IntegerField(max_length=8)
    fines = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    next_due = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)


    def json_data(self):
        return {
            'next_due': self.next_due,
            'holds_ready': self.holds_ready,
            'fines': self.fines
            }
```

Running python manage.py shell:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Sep 27 2012, 21:16:52)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)

>>> import ...    
>>> account = get_account("jave")    
>>> print account.next_due    
2014-05-27
>>> print account.holds_ready    
1
>>> print account.fines
5.35        
>>> a = account.json_data()    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>    
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'json_data'
```

Could someone shed some light on why the json_data method is not recognized? 
I searched existing posts. but couldn't find the answer.

```
>>> print dir(account)
    ['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', u'__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_base_manager', '_default_manager', '_deferred', '_do_insert', '_do_update', '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD', '_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks', '_meta', '_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_save_parents', '_save_table', '_set_pk_val', '_state', 'account_id', 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'date_error_message', 'delete', 'fines', 'full_clean', 'holds_ready', 'id', 'items_loaned', 'name', 'next_due', 'objects', 'parent_account_id', 'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'root_account_id', 'save', 'save_base', 'serializable_value', 'sis_account_id', 'unique_error_message', 'validate_unique']
```

Comment: Nothing looks terribly wrong with this to me at first glance.  Perhaps you should use introspection to take a look at the account object?  Inspect its `__class__`, its `__dict__`, etc. and see if anything strikes you as odd?

Comment: can you try a print dir(account) ?

Comment: What is `get_account()` doing exactly?

Comment: Reply to Burhan Khalid:get_account() creates an Account object.

Comment: Your file is not saved correctly, because the object returned is missing your new method. Try running a `syncdb` to update the cache.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Unless I'm mistaken, `syncdb` wouldn't affect the methods defined in `models.py` (only the `models.ModelField` attributes that are then copied in the database)

Comment: To BurhanKhalid: had run syncdb. no effect.

Comment: @Andrew Gorcester Thank you for the hints! Inspecting its __class__ found the cause: it refers to another class with the same name.

Comment: Glad that worked out!